# Continuous Integration: Codeship + Gulp (Jasmine)

Tags: codeship, gulp-jasmine

My Continuous Integration works pretty great using Codeship except one thing: **stop deploying and alert us when unit tests are failing**.

Here is our current commands:

1. npm install
2. npm install bower
3. bower install
4. gulp test
5. gulp build

The problem is whether `gulp test` end with success or fail, the `gulp build` builds.

I succeed to `console.log()` my `gulp test` exit status but I have no idea about how to make Codeship listen to this exit status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @mlocker answer and [this discussion on Github](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/587), I've found a workaround that works fine for me:

```
gulp.task('test', function (done) {
  karma.start({}, function(exitStatus){
    done(exitStatus ? "There are failing unit tests" : undefined);
  });
});
```

The trick here is that if the exitStatus is different from 0, you'll get a formatError on "There are failing unit tests" which will exit `gulp test` with `1` making Codeship to stop and consider the build as `failed`.

Answer (score 2):

The build on Codeship will fail as soon as any command exits with an exit code other than zero.

Please make sure this is the case with running `gulp test`.

(You can also reach out to us via support@codeship.com if any other questions come up!)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try chaining the test and build tasks?

```
gulp test && gulp build
```

Comment: Actually, as @mlocher pointed out, the problem was `gulp test` will always exit with success, so `gulp build` will always be called anyway.